# What is the correct/update format for calling contract functions with near-sdk-js : contract.methodName(args, gas, amount) deprecated

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm seeing a warning message in my test code related to a depreciated format for a function call, but I can't seem to figure out how to correct the code.

1. the line numbers don't seem to match lines with contract function calls  (e.g. error shows src/test.js:17:25  which I would assume is line 17 col 25, but that line doesn't have a contract call on it at all (line 17 is `describe('entries', function () {`
2. I've tried to look to see for any patterns and it appears to be the 3 instances that are contract call functions (i.e. those that need to change data) on lines 20, 30 and 35, but I'm not clear on how the format should be changed.

I've looked in the source and he message seems to generated from the near-api-js contract.js (line 86/87).

As far as I can tell, my calls seem to be formatted as requested.. but I'm obviously missing something.

Can someone clarify what the updated format should be?

The warning messages are:

```
contract.methodName(args, gas, amount) deprecated use `contract.methodName({ args, gas?, amount?, callbackUrl?, meta? })` instead src/test.js:17:25
contract.methodName(args, gas, amount) deprecated use `contract.methodName({ args, gas?, amount?, callbackUrl?, meta? })` instead src/test.js:27:22
Receipt: EEpCJZxmJ7i5rYC12Lx6KH2ZyiEnpycxDBeyBBucGVfx
        Log [test-account-1640297754138-4833979]: Entry Added!
contract.methodName(args, gas, amount) deprecated use `contract.methodName({ args, gas?, amount?, callbackUrl?, meta? })` instead src/test.js:36:22
```

My code:

```
 1 describe('Token', function () {
  2   let near;
  3   let contract;
  4   let accountId;
  5
  6   beforeAll(async function () {
  7     console.log('nearConfig', nearConfig);
  8     near = await nearlib.connect(nearConfig);
  9     accountId = nearConfig.contractName;
 10     contract = await near.loadContract(nearConfig.contractName, {
 11       viewMethods: ['num_entries'],
 12       changeMethods: ['new','add_entry', 'reset_log'],
 13       sender: accountId
 14     });
 15   });
 16
 17   describe('entries', function () {
 18
 19     it('can be initialized', async function() {
 20       await contract.new();
 21       const endCounter = await contract.num_entries();
 22       expect(endCounter).toEqual(0);
 23     });
 24     it('can be accessed', async function() {
 25       const endCounter = await contract.num_entries();
 26       expect(endCounter).toEqual(0);
 27     });
 28     it('can add entries', async function () {
 29       const startCounter = await contract.num_entries();
 30       await contract.add_entry({ "timestamp" : "Time1","name" : "My Name","message": "My Message"});
 31       const endCounter = await contract.num_entries();
 32       expect(endCounter).toEqual(startCounter + 1);
 33     });
 34     it('can be reset', async function () {
 35       await contract.reset_log();
 36       const endCounter = await contract.num_entries(args={});
 37       expect(endCounter).toEqual(0);
 38     });
 39   });
 40 });
```

### Update 12/26/21

Don't feel I'm qualified to answer how this is *intended* to work so I'll update my question with what I found.

The code in api-sdk-js appears to be want no more than a single argument:

```
if (args.length > 1 || !(args[0] && args[0].args)) 
     const deprecate = depd_1.default('contract.methodName(args, gas, amount)');
```

I changed my calls such that args was a named parameter in an object,i.e. I replaced:

```
await contract.add_entry({ "timestamp" : "Time1","name" : "My Name","message": "My Message"});
```

with

```
await contract.add_entry({"args" : { "timestamp" : "Time1","name" : "My Name","message": "My Message"}});
```

and

```
await contract.new();
```

with

```
await contract.new({"args" : {}});
```

That made the warning messages go away.. and I can sort of understand what the warning message is trying to say...

Is this the actually the desired new format and its just that the Docs just aren't updated yet with the new format (https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-quick-reference#call-contract)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My guess is there is some underlying call happening that is deprecated

Consider studying these examples
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/starter--near-api-js/blob/main/contract-advanced.html

Or these examples
https://github.com/Learn-NEAR/NCD.L2.sample--lottery/blob/main/src/services/near.js

Comment: Ok.  Those examples seem to use a different call "wallet.functionCall"  than contract.method, but looked at those did give me an idea..